# Store a Model Class in a Session in ASP.NET Core

Tags: asp.net-core

Hi guys can someone help me with the code to store a model class in a session in Asp.NET Core

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ASP.NET Core Session object has 3 methods to set the session value, which are `Set`, `SetInt32` and `SetString`. The `Set` method accepts a byte array as an argument where the `SetInt32` and `SetString` method are the extension methods of the `Set` method.

To store complex objects, we need to create an extension class to store and retrieve objects in session. Here, the object is converted into JSON and stored as a string. Later, it is retrieved as a string and deserialized to the original object. Like,

```
public static class SessionExtensions
{
  public static void SetObject(this ISession session, string key, object value)
  {
    session.SetString(key, JsonConvert.SerializeObject(value));
  }

  public static T GetObject<T>(this ISession session, string key)
  {
    var value = session.GetString(key);
    return value == null ? default(T) : JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(value);
  }
}
```

Now, you can store your complex objects as shown below:

```
var cart = new Cart { Id = 1, Name = "Cart1" };
HttpContext.Session.SetObject("Cart", cart);
```

and get them as below:

```
var obj=HttpContext.Session.GetObject<Cart>("Cart");
```

Startup.cs

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.Configure<CookiePolicyOptions>(options =>
        {
            // This lambda determines whether user consent for non-essential cookies is needed for a given request.
            options.CheckConsentNeeded = context => true;
            options.MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.None;
        });

        services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_2);

        services.AddSession(opts =>
        {
             opts.Cookie.IsEssential = true;// make the session cookie Essential
        });
    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        ...
        app.UseSession();

        app.UseMvc(routes =>
        {
            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "default",
                template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
        });
    }
```